# VB.NET Get Relative Location of Longitude/Latitude point with Distance and Initial Point

Tags: vb.net, gis, latitude-longitude

I am using VB.NET and want to calculate the `Longitude` and `Latitude` of a point directly EAST of a given point when given a distance of kilometers.

In this example, Point 1 has the longitude of `-118.243683` and Latitude of `34.052235`. I know that the distance between these two points are exactly 30 kilometers. How do I find the exact Longitude and Latitude of the second point? I know that is is possible to find the distance between two points but I do not know how to find the longitude and latitude of a second point when given a first point and a relative distance (in kilometers) away is 30.

Assuming that the angle is zero degrees between the two points, how do I find the point (in Longitude and Latitude) of the second point?

[image: Points]

Comment: It won't be zero degrees. The earth spins 6° per hour. In 24 hours 360°. If you know the circumference of the earth at latttude 34 it simple. `R = √ [ (r1² * cos(B))² + (r2² * sin(B))² ] / [ (r1 * cos(B))² + (r2 * sin(B))² ]` = `6371.489`. https://rechneronline.de/earth-radius/ PS a KL-1 is a calculator. And in the past this KL-1 was a computer calculating `radiation reading * time = radiation dosage` so I was known as a computer. It wasn't till later computer referred to non humans.

Comment: Opps 15° per hour. 6° per hour is each twilight (astronomical, nautical, and civil) = 24 mins each.